# Android клиент-сервер

Tags: php, java, android

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь отправить видео на сервер:
Вот класс с которым я работаю:

```
public class Upload {

    public static final String UPLOAD_URL= "http://simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/VideoUpload/upload.php";

    private int serverResponseCode;

    public String uploadVideo(String file) {

        String fileName = file;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        File sourceFile = new File(file);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("Huzza", "Source File Does not exist");
            return null;
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("myFile", fileName);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                        .getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                rd.close();
            } catch (IOException ioex) {
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }else {
            return "Could not upload";
        }
    }
```

Я у меня ошибка при отправке на сервер, я подозреваю, что неправильно указал путь к файлу пхп(Пробовал еще через ИП). ПХП лежит в папке -WAMP/www/VideoUpload/upload.php  и вот сам скрипт:

```
<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 $file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
 $file_size = $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
 $temp_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];

 $location = "uploads/";

 move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$file_name);
 echo "http://xxx/VideoUpload/uploads/".$file_name;
 }else{
 echo "Error";
 }
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Попробуйте поменять на `https://simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/VideoUpload/upload.php`

Comment: я пробовал- 404

Comment: Так ошибка 404 и с вашим адресом, значит дело в ссылке, убедитесь что путь правильный

Comment: так в этом и состоит суть моего вопроса, просто я пробовал через ИП и локалхост, но происходит ошибка, как еще можно прописать url???

Answer (score 1):

вы уверены что uploads папка находится рядом со скриптом ?

если да то

```
$location = __DIR__."/uploads/";
```

если нет то надо смотреть где.

Вот например если на уровень выше

```
$location = __DIR__."../uploads/";
```

Если на два

```
$location = __DIR__."../../uploads/";
```

ну и т.п.